# Python contar vocales

Tags: python

Indicar que artículos vendidos tienen menos vocales en sus nombres.
Mi codigo es:

```
 def vocalesbusq(tupla):
        return tupla[0]

 def contar_vocales(vocalesbusq):
        voc = 0
        for c in tupla:
                if c in "aeiouAEIOU":
                    voc = voc + 1
        return voc
 print("Son:", voc)
```

Quisiera saber que estoy planteando mal

Comment: `tupla` no existe en la función, imagino que debiera ser `vocalesbusq`

Comment: Me aparece que voc no esta definida

Comment: Si claro, `voc` es una variable interna de la función `contar_vocales` y tratas de acceder desde afuera. En principio, con el cambio que te mencioné `contar_vocales` debería funcionar correctamente, lo que tienes que hacer es pasarle por parámetro cada uno de los nombres y guardar la salida que sería la cantidad de vocales.